# how to add a vertical scrollview

Tags: objective-c, xcode

i ve got a view which contains buttons and textview .what i want is to scroll vertically...cud u guys help me out below is the code...

```
- (id)initWithItem:(NSString *)theItem Title:(NSString *)title Description:(NSString *)detaildesc{
if (self = [super initWithNibName:@"Secondetailview" bundle:nil]) {
self.theItem1=theItem;
    self.theTitle=title;

    UILabel *tit = [[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 200, 25)] autorelease];                        
    [tit setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    [tit setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [tit setText:self.theTitle];  
    [tit setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16]];
    NSLog(@" wii this is cool:%@",detaildesc);            
     [self.view addSubview:tit];


    label1.text=detaildesc;
    label1.numberOfLines=4;
    label1.textColor=[UIColor grayColor];


}

    return self;
   }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a UIScrollview inside the tab and then adjust the contentSize of the UIScrollView to the size of the total height of all your controls.

Comment: i ve added uiscroll view in the interface builder.I m not able to proceed after dat..could u modify de above code....

Comment: @kingston, if you have a uiviewcontroller with a nib, delete the view, add a uiscrollview, link the uiscrollview as view of the uiviewcontroller, and then add this code in viewDidLoad: self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500); where 500 would be the total height of the whole thing.

Comment: i added the above line i m getting an error saying scrollView undeclared..if i add the scroll view as IBoutlet and linked to view  even that aint working

Answer (score 0):

In contentSize you have to increase the Y value

Comment: i ve removed uiviewcontroller and added uiscrollview which i linked to the uiview ...could u help me to proceed further on....what should i add in uiiew so that i have the scrolling effect

Comment: Add som63.e06 +3. scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,600);

Comment: add somelabels and buttons to scrollview.Then scrollview.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320,500);It adds the scrolling effect